# XOM analogue for Scala?

Tags: xml, scala, xom

Is there an XML processing library for Scala "that strives for correctness, simplicity, and performance, *in that order*" like does [XOM](http://xom.nu) for Java? (Scala XML API is not an option)

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if you explain why the Scala XML API is not suitable.

Comment: There are many things. From various names which are not canonical or do not correspond to XML specification (e.g. `label` instead of `localName` in `Elem`) to awkward API spots (e.g. try iterating over attributes of `Elem`). Pattern matching constructs seem totally unreadable to me. And I like clear code. And in some cases I prefer mutable nodes (immutability is not an axiom in Scala, right?)

Comment: I'm not trying to defend `scala.xml`, because I do think there are some weird problems, but you can just can `.attributes.iterator` on an `Elem` to get an `Iterator` over its attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only alternative XML library for Scala as far as I know is [anti-xml](https://github.com/djspiewak/anti-xml), which is an effort started not two weeks ago. It is not really useful for anything right now, but you can at least try to influence its development if you find it worthy.

Comment: Excellent! It's been disheartening to hear over and over again that Scala's XML support is broken and that nobody seems to care to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was asking this question to find out if someone already started a replacement project where I can participate. Actually I like the ideas briefly described in `anti-xml` very much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

In case others come here, [Scales Xml](http://code.google.com/p/scala-scales/) is the most XOM like, in fact its correctness extends to modelling QNames directly, sharing the model with both DOM and Pull Parsing and even correcting annoying JAXP impl serialization errors (bad cdata splits etc).

Its also faster than Scala Xml, whilst providing lower memory usage.

I'm not sure about simpler though, as that's mostly dependent on the users perspective.  It does however strive to be simple through both better use of the type system and providing an XPath Dsl for most of its tree handling.

Its a radically different approach for most xml handling, whereas Anti-Xml looks very similar to Scala Xml.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply wrap the absolutely excellent XOM with implicit conversions and such?
Yes, it won't give you scala's XML-native-syntax style out of the box...